# how to keep server running when using npm run build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, server, digital-ocean

I have a React app running on a Digital Ocean "Droplet" and when ever I want to upload the most recent version of the app (via github), I use npm run build (after using git pull). The problem is, when I run npm run build, it overwrites the old files (which is expected) but if you try to access the website during this time, you get an error (on the website). Is there a way to keep the site up while I update the production code to the newest git pull/commit?

I know there may be ways to have the server redirect to another server, but am unsure how to do this during downtime, nor do I have another server setup. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very sure on that. But can you try installing serve using npm and then try running the command `serve -s <folder_name>`. This might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of ways for managing this case.

The issue is that when the build task starts, it takes quite long usually (also 2/3 minutes) and it clears up the dist/build folder while running.

What you can do now as easy fix is to serve another folder of your application, not the one target by the build. 
Then at the end of the build script, chain a script for copying the build folder to the served folder.

In this way the application is still served during the build, and when the task ends, the new build will be moved into the served folder.